# ASP.Net WebSite Membership AND C# Windows Form Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

*This is not real, it's just a project i'm working on*

I've created a Hotel Management system in C# WindowsForm, it allows staff members to Add/Edit/Update Rooms,Reservation and Customers etc.

Along side this Windows-form i'm creating an ASP.net WebSite where customers should be able to register and reserve rooms online. I've come to the point where i need to create some-type of membership method for this website which should correspond to the membership of the windows form. However i'm not sure what method of membership would be best suited for this, i have looked into the asp.net membership, it's what i want however it creates it's own schema and i don't know how i can relate the information to my customers table and c#windows form.

I would ideally like it to resemble a real-life situation as much as possible anyway, am i going about this the wrong way? in terms of the c# windows-form what other technology  would a business use to manage a system like this where they can add/edit/update there system and have a website which relates.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

The asp.net membership system is a pretty good system and is certainly worth learning.

It's not as hard as you think to relate the web and WinForms systems - you could map the membership users guid to a windows forms users Id in a separate table, or add a foreign key column to the existing membership table that links to a User Id.

You can write scripts that synchronise passwords (if a WinForms user changes their pwd, update the web pwd too). It's all doable.

I'm sorry I can't be more specific without knowing your system, but I would encourage you to carry on as you are and use the asp.net membership system in your website, rather than writing your own.

Comment: This seems quite encouraging, I'll carry on with the ASP.net membership then. Only discouraging part is that i don't see many tutorials on specifically what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth learning Membership system, and it provide some important features out of box that deal with security issues.

For understanding the database schema just follow this step:
Goto: **SystemDrive:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\YourFrameworkVersion\aspnet_regsql**

Now Create a database using this tool. Look at the fields and relationships. It generally creates 11 tables, but you may go through **Users, Roles, UsersInRoles** tables. These are the tables userd for Authentication and Authorization.
If you want to user your own database and want to work with Membership system, then you may need to extend the Membership class, [this article](http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/) will be helpful for that.

Comment: Hi thnx, but i'm not using MVC.

Comment: Well conversion wouldn`t be that tough form mvc to webforms, because the main concern is the class that is overriding MembershipProvider. This procedure will same for both mvc & webform. Have a try.